# How many Threads can be run 20 cpu and 1 thread per cpu?

Tags: multithreading

My Configuration:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                20
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-19
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             20
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 85
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8168 CPU @ 2.70GHz
Stepping:              0
CPU MHz:               2700.000
BogoMIPS:              5400.00
Hypervisor vendor:     VMware
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              1024K
L3 cache:              33792K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-19
```

On my machine above configuration is running. How many max threads can run on this config?

Comment: The theoretical max depends on how much RAM you have.

Answer (score 0):

As many as you create.

To say it blunt: your question doesn't really make sense. Probably, you are rather asking "what would be an *ideal* number of threads"?

But that question can only be answered when knowing **context**, in other words: details about the **workload** to run.

"More threads" aren't necessarily going to speed up things.

When your workload is CPU intensive, say: loading large files from memory, and en/derypting them, then you want to restrict the number of software threads by the number the hardware supports (like 20 in your case).

If your workload is I/O intensive, and your software is *waiting* for I/O a lot, then you might use hundreds, if not thousands of threads easily.

Long story short: hardware details alone aren't sufficient to determine the number of threads to use.